# Calculating the size of application data in wireshark

Tags: tls

I am new to SSL. My doubt is how to calculate the application data in SSL.

Ex: When I launch 'https://www.ask.com/' in my browser, a series of events takes place internally - on the server side the data on ask.com is divided into packets and sent to my computer & then its displayed on my computer.

When I get the contents of ask.com I know that the web page is successfully displayed. But is there any way to cross verify? Like checking the size of ask.com & verifying it in wireshark?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "cross verify"? Do you want to verify that you are really talking with ask.com, and not with another party? (I.e. that you do not have a Man-In-The-Middle attack or malicious redirect?)

Comment: None of this appears to be security-related. Wireshark statistical analysis will tell you the data size of a conversation (look in the menus). As for having something to compare against, how do you propose to do that? If banner ads are used, then every request to the same page could be a different size.